# Anchor tags not working in jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is an image slider at the top of this page:

http://www.example.com/

Each slide is wrapped in an anchor tag and is supposed to link to a post somewhere else on the site. However, the slides don't seem to be clickable and I can't figure out why. My suspicion is that there must be some sort of z-index issue but hours of tinkering hasn't gotten me anywhere. Ideas?

Comment: I see you've solved the problem, what was the cause?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with the z-indexing thing. I kinda suspected that might be the problem but changing the z-index meant solving another problem I was trying to avoid like the pluage. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you put the z-index property for fix the URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I would have tried:

1. The a-tag should probably have its display css property set to block.
2. One of the slideshow containers has its z-index set to -1. This could result in it's content effectively being covered by another element for click purposes.